# Tcl add a symbol N time at the end of the string

Tags: string, tcl

How I can add N white-spaces at the end of the string, when for example N = (25 - string_length)? Is there a command that does this procedure directly or I should use a loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way to tackle this is with the format command, if you know that you want a string of length 25 that is right padded with spaces then:

```
% format "|%-25s|" hello
|hello                    |
```

should do this. (The | is just there to delimit the result).  It's also possible to use a variable to set the total width of the output:

```
% set width 25
25
% format "|%-*s|" $width hello
|hello                    |
```

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to do this:

### With format

```
set padded [format "%-25s" $str]
```

(Also see [Jackson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075418/tcl-add-a-symbol-n-time-at-the-end-of-the-string/5075592#5075592) for this.)

### With string repeat

```
set padded $str[string repeat " " [expr {25 - [string length $str]}]]
```

### With append in a loop

```
for {set padded $str} {[string length $padded] < 25} {} {
    append padded " "
}
```

### With binary format

```
set padded [binary format "A25" $str]
```

(Note that this is only safe for characters up to `\u00FF`.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string repeat`, i.e.

```
% string repeat : 25
:::::::::::::::::::::::::
```